# clarification on why BG has no action

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I got confused by the page ([Are these two definitions of $EG$ equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471149/are-these-two-definitions-of-eg-equivalent)) about the following.

Doesn't this also define an action on BG?

Comment: Strictly speaking, $BG$ does not have a $G$-action, right? It is, somehow, the quotient of $EG$ by $G$. There is a projection $EG \to BG$, and this projection forgets the action because it drops the $G$-action component of $EG$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $G$-simplicial set $X$ is cofibrant if, and only if, each $X_n$ has a free $G$-action. The only sensible $G$-action on $BG$ is the trivial $G$-action. But the trivial action is not free: every simplex is a fixed point! Thus, $BG$ is not cofibrant as a $G$-simplicial set.

Your confusion might arise from trying to see the object $BG$, whose natural category is $\mathsf{sSet}$, inside of $G-\mathsf{sSet}$. A different question is whether $BG$ is cofibrant in $\mathsf{sSet}$, and this is indeed the case: all simplicial sets are cofibrant.